# Curly braces in the language of set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, first-order-logic

We usually write sets using curly braces. However the language of set theory(i.e. the first-order language with the only binary relation-symbol $\in$) doesn't have curly braces. How is it justify in mathematical logic?

Comment: How do you justify using curly braces in mathematical logic?

Comment: Umm... I think all of the notations using curly braces is constant symbols added in the language of set theory by extensions by definitions though it ’s a brute force method...

Comment: For example $X=\{1,2,3\}$ is short for $$x\in X \leftrightarrow (x=1\lor x=2\lor x=3)$$

Comment: I think that's a necessary property, but there is a gap in terms of mathematical logic. We don't know where the symbol {1,2,3} came from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a term-forming operator: when applied to a formula it outputs a *term* (a "name").

> $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}$

is the name of the set of all and only those elements that satisfy formula $\varphi(x)$.

We can add it to the basic language through the definition:

> $\{ x \mid \varphi(x) \}=y \leftrightarrow [\forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))]$,

provided that we have previously proved that :

> $\exists y [\forall x (x \in y \leftrightarrow \varphi(x))]$.

The key property of the symbol is that:

> $z \in \{ x \mid \varphi(x) \} \leftrightarrow \varphi(z)$.

Comment: Thank you for answer and edit! A term-forming operator seems to be what I have been looking for. I'll look into it.

Comment: @beginner_nt - you are welcome.